# Are Technological Standards bodies required to be approved by the government?

Tags: us-federal-government, antitrust-law

In the interest of cross vendor compatibility, the method by which different technologies interoperate is often standardized. This means that a non binding agreement is made between multiple parties to abide by rules set forth in a documented standard.

Examples of this include The USB Device Working Group, Jedec, The C++ Standards Committee, and PCI-SIG.

While presumably in the public's interest, these groups appear to be a fragrant violation of antitrust laws. Do they require a special license to operate?

If so, what would such a license look like and what agency would issue it?

Answer (score 3):

Standards-setting by industry groups is not inherently anti-competitive and these groups do not require a licence from the government to operate. They are a prototypical example of "private ordering" (see David J. Teece & Edward F. Sherry, "Standards Setting and Antitrust" (2003) [87 Minn. L.R. 1913](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/217211884.pdf), p. 1987).

What can be anti-competitive is when a corporation advocates for an element to be included in a standard for reasons other than technical considerations. See e.g. the International Standards Organization's "[Competition Law Guidelines](https://www.iso.org/files/live/sites/isoorg/files/developing_standards/docs/en/competition_law_guidelines.pdf)."

An example violation is [the behaviour of Rambus, Inc.](https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/news/press-releases/2007/02/ftc-issues-final-opinion-order-rambus-matter):

> According to the FTC complaint, Rambus nonetheless participated in JEDEC’s DRAM standard-setting activities for more than four years without disclosing to JEDEC or its members that it was actively working to develop, and possessed, a patent and several pending patent applications that involved specific technologies ultimately adopted in the standards.
>
> ...
>
> In its liability opinion dated July 31, 2006, the Commission found that, “Rambus engaged in exclusionary conduct that significantly contributed to its acquisition of monopoly power in four related markets.”

In [another example](https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/news/speeches/antitrust-intellectual-property-law-adversaries-partners#a.%20Complaint%20allegations), Dell Computer Corporation was alleged to have

> voted to approve the VL-bus standard and certified that the standard did not infringe its intellectual property. After the standard became very successful, Dell asserted an earlier-issued patent against several computer manufacturers using the standard.

The FTC entered a consent agreement with Dell:

> prohibiting Dell from enforcing its patent against those who wanted to use the VL-bus standard. The FTC's order also prohibited Dell from enforcing patent rights in the future when it intentionally failed to disclose those rights upon request of a standards-setting organization.

Comment: I would argue that creating standards is **pro** competitive, as having one standard to regulate... pipe fittings allows companies to easier compete as their pipes are known to fit to any other pipe under the same standard - and puts them into competition for prices.